# Executing Javascript file from AS 3.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, actionscript-3

I am running a small jquery code to my web page:

```
<!-- myjs.js -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
$("body").append('<div id="ajaxBusy" class="ajaxBusy"></div>');
</script>
```

as you can see i am adding a div at my html body with specific class and id name.

How is it possible to execute this .js file throught actionscript 3.0?
I mean to make a flash movie and call this file, or is it possible to execute inline javascript code through AS 3.0?

I found the code bellow but i cant make it work:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

var someVarInAS : String = 'foo';
var someOtherVarInAS : int = 10;
var jsXML : XML = 
<script type="text/javascript">
    var someVarInJS = '{$("body").append('<div id="ajaxBusy" class="ajaxBusy"></div>');}';
    var someOtherVarInJS = '{$('#ajaxBusy).fadeIn();}';
    <![CDATA[       
        alert( 'this comes from flash: ' + someVarInJS + ', ' + someOtherVarInJS );
    ]]>
</script>;

ExternalInterface.call( "function js_" + ( new Date().getTime() ) + "(){ " + jsXML + " }" );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this for loading JS files dynamically from AS3 and it works pretty well. Could be modified to run normal js rather than load another file:

```
var script:String = "" + 
    "var newscript = document.createElement('script');" +
    "newscript.type = 'text/javascript';" +
    "newscript.async = true;" +
    "newscript.src = 'SomeJavascriptFile.js';" +
    "(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]||document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(newscript);";

if ( ExternalInterface.available ) {
    ExternalInterface.call("eval", script);
}
```

Comment: I think ExternalInterface may be globally available. I do not have any specific imports for it in my code.

Comment: i put your code and replace my .js file but nothing happened.. any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

You could also avoid having to write javascript within actionscript and keep the two separate in their separate spots. Then just call the method name only using ExternalInterface, instead of calling 'eval' and passing in your javascript. It may be easier to test and maintain down the road.

Inside your html file:

```
<script>
    function addDiv(){
        // stuff here that adds the div you want, such as what you had:
        $("body").append('<div id="ajaxBusy" class="ajaxBusy"></div>');
    }
</script>
```

Then inside flash:

```
if (ExternalInterface.available == true) {
    ExternalInterface.call("addDiv");
}
```

You can also supply method arguments from flash to javascript if needed as well.

Comment: how the as3 code will understand which .js file must to load? or fistrly i need to insert my jquery code inside my html? i need the as3 to load and run my .js file remotely..

Comment: yes, your jquery code would be inside the html and it's just the actual execution call that would be done by flash.